# как писать слова в одно сообщение

Tags: python, telebot

у меня появился вопрос. как писать данные и слова в одном сообщении? например:

```
bot.send_message(bot.from_user.id, username, "написал", message.text)
```

но вот только через запятую не работает. можно ли писать данные и слова в одно сообщение?

Comment: преобразуйте данные в строку и отправляйте

Comment: @5c0rp спасибо большое!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте f-строки:

```
bot.send_message(bot.from_user.id, f"{username} написал {message.text}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Для send_message нужно преобразовать все в строку и ее уже отправлять.
Для файлов send_audio, send_video и тд.

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]